# Background image in PDF using iTextSharp.text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm unable to set the background image for the PDF in my .aspx script.

My script:

```
  string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/1.jpg";

    iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);

    // Page site and margin left, right, top, bottom is defined
     Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

     jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;

      jpg.ScaleToFit(1070, 650);


    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();

    pdfDoc.NewPage();

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("TEST");

    pdfDoc.Add(jpg);

    pdfDoc.Add(paragraph);

    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);

    Response.End();
```

Here is what it looks like:
https://snag.gy/knfJSB.jpg

img itself: 3900x2174

How do I make it as PDF background?

**EDITED:**

All i had to do was to have ethe exact dimension of the image. I also changed the code to:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

     jpg.ScaleToFit(790, 777);
```

And it looks good now. Hope it helps for others.

Comment: Your question is duplicated at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673436/how-do-i-insert-a-background-image-on-all-pages-of-a-pdf-document

Comment: Its different situation and that solution does not work. thx